# Can't find a list of hex key when using modifers (shift, alt, ctrl) C++

Tags: c++, hex

```
 RegisterHotKey(0, ZERO_KEYID, 0, 0x60) // Registers as numpad 0
```

Ok I am trying to set up hotkeys and As you can see above I need the hex value for the keyboard. I can find all the values without modifiers but how can I find when using modifiers such as shift, ctrl, alt?

Comment: What is a "bonus question"?

Comment: It's the question [so] win when the OP is too lazy to ask separate question @EdHeal

Comment: I thought they were related in the sense that you alter the hex code in the same way you would do with modifiers but i'll delete it off since it seems to draw more attention than the actual question.

Comment: This should help if you're working in Windows
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640208/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-determine-a-key-press-and-key-holding-in-win32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple google request brings you Microsoft's website for RegisterHotKey and there you find it:

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx][1]

The third parameter lets you specify the modifier(s) like:

RegisterHotKey (0, ZERO_KEYID, MOD_CONTROL|MODSHIFT, 0x60);

As far as I know there is no way of detecting when two arbitrary keys (like '1' and '2') are being pressed simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the MSDN documentation on `RegisterHotKey`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx