# How do you write an IsPressed (a function that should only return true on first press)?

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard

I need a function in a game loop that should only return true on first press.

I don't know which game I can give an example from which game is currently on the market, but I will explain this request in detail (I haven't played/can't play any of the modern games because I'm blind).

For example, there is an event you are listening to in the loop. When the user presses the **S** key, a text showing the last status of the character appears on the screen: Stamina, energy etc.
This loop can run thousands of times per second, as the loops depend on the speed of the hardware and the code you write.
We only need to detect the first press of the user. It should return false when the key is hold pressed. Otherwise, the last status of the user is shown thousands of times on the screen.

I am trying to provide this functionality using win32api. [GetAsyncKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) seems like the right option for this scenario but I don't understand how this can be done.

```cpp
bool IsPressed(int key) {
return GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 1 != 0;
}
```

The function I wrote acts like a char event.

How can I write this?

I tried using other answers on StackOwerflow. However, I could not find an answer to the question I asked. Still, these answers helped me with some issues:
[What is the fastest way to determine a key press and key holding in Win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640208/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-determine-a-key-press-and-key-holding-in-win32)

Comment: You need to keep track of the previous state of the key and compare it with the current state. When the two differ, update the previous state and return true; otherwise return false.

Comment: If you *truly* want to call a function only once, use [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once). But that's probably not what you want. Instead you need to keep a state of the keys, if the key is currently pressed or not. If the state is "not pressed" but `GetAsyncKeyState` indicates it is pressed, then you change the state to "pressed" and return true. If the state is "pressed" and `GetAsyncKeyState` indicates that the key is no longer pressed, then set the state to "not pressed" and return false. In all other cases return false (leaving the state as it is).

Comment: *"I need a function in a game loop that should only return true on first press."* - Why don't you use synchronous input handling then?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you shouldn't write code that runs at thousands of times per second if it doesn't need to. For games, it's enough to run at the frame rate. For physics simulations, you'll want to run faster (and more deterministically) than the frame rate. Physics and display are decoupled. If this is a text-based game turn based RPG, and play only progresses on user input, then you only need to check for user input quickly (10 times per second, or register a callback handler for all of the keys you care about). Logic only needs to run one iteration per confirmed user input.

Answer (score 0):

While the [GetAsyncKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) *can* indicate via least significant bit whether the key has been pressed since the last call to this function, this behavior cannot be relied on.

> If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState. However, you should not rely on this last behavior...

> Although the least significant bit of the return value indicates whether the key has been pressed since the last query, due to the preemptive multitasking nature of Windows, another application can call GetAsyncKeyState and receive the "recently pressed" bit instead of your application.

Therefore, you can't rely on the Windows API to do the bookkeeping for you. I suggest wrapping any key queries in a class that you'll use for any button presses.

```
class KeyInput {
public:
    using key_type = int;

    enum class Transition {
        none,
        pressed,
        released,
    };

    struct PressResult {
        bool pressed;
        Transition transition;
    };

    PressResult state(key_type key) {
        PressResult result;
        result.pressed = (GetAsyncKeyState(key) < 0);
        if (auto it = last_states_.find(key); it != last_states_.end()) {
            if (last_states_[key] == result.pressed) {
                result.transition = Transition::none;
            }
            else if (result.pressed) {
                result.transition = Transition::pressed;
            }
            else {
                result.transition = Transition::released;
            }
        }
        else {
            result.transition = Transition::none;
        }

        last_states_[key] = result.pressed;

        return result;
    };

private:
    std::unordered_map<key_type, bool> last_states_{}; 
};
```

[See it in action](https://godbolt.org/z/MTGnWej5j)

#### Note

This will not capture transitions since the last iteration of your program. In order to handle that, you'll need your class to check every button press (that you care about) on every iteration.

Comment: Surely, you meant to say *"least significant bit"*.

Comment: @IInspectable I did thank you. That changes what my call to the API looks like as well. Anyone know the canonical way to check the MSB of a SHORT in windows?

Comment: `< 0` is pretty much the canonical way. I won't claim to know what sort of conversion or type promotion is involved according to C or C++ language standards is involved here.

Comment: makes sense to me

Comment: The `SHORT` is promoted to whatever type `int` is (since we're comparing against an int of `0`). This includes sign extension, so it'll become `0xffff8000` for 32-bit int, etc. Perfectly legal and defined.

Answer (score 0):

After working on it a more, I realized that I cannot do this with GetAsyncKeyState or a similar function. I wrote something simple using Windows' callback and event system.
I didn't care about data race and other issues. You probably need to use a **mutex** but that depends on your code.

The code below keeps the state of the keys in an array. Changes are sent to the array with a function by the callback.

If you compile the program in console mode, you will see that it is printed to the console only once when you press A. It was exactly what I was looking for.

To compile you can use:

`g++ minimal.cpp`

- You can press **a** to test it on a standard querty keyboard.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>


// We define a struct that holds the key state.
// firstPress will be updated by IsPressed.
struct keyState {
    bool firstPress;
    bool down;
};

// We have an Array-based collection of keys. Changes will be made by callback.
std::vector<keyState> allKeyStates(256);


void keyProcess(unsigned short key, bool down)
{
        if(down) {
        if(!allKeyStates[key].down) {
            allKeyStates[key].down = true;
            allKeyStates[key].firstPress = true;
        }
        return;
    }
    allKeyStates[key].down = false;
    allKeyStates[key].firstPress = false;
}


bool IsPressed(unsigned short key)
{
    if(allKeyStates[key].firstPress) {
        allKeyStates[key].firstPress = false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// forward decleration
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int main()
{
MSG msg          = {0};
    HWND handle;

    WNDCLASS wc      = {0}; 
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance     = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
    wc.lpszClassName = "mini_windows_test";
    if( !RegisterClass(&wc) )
        return -1;
    handle = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, "Minimal Key handling application", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE, 0,0, 640, 480, 0, 0, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    if(handle == NULL)
        return -1;

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        if(IsPressed(0x41)) {
            std::cout << "Key A: it will only be print on the first press. Holding the key will not run repeatedly.\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message) {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            keyProcess((unsigned short)wParam, true);
            break;
        case WM_KEYUP:
            keyProcess((unsigned short)wParam, false);
            break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
 }
return 0;
}
```

Apologize for the bady English and typos. You can edit my question and my answer if it works for you.

Comment: The [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) message includes information on the previous key state. You don't have to keep track of this information yourself.

Comment: @IInspectable - Can you elaborate on what you want to say?
Is it a misuse (works as I want according to my testing)?

Comment: Storing state information isn't required to determine whether a `WM_KEYDOWN` message is the result of an initial key press or automatic key repeat. The documentation explains which information is available. It's generally not desirable to store redundant state. And there's a fairly serious issue here, too: Indexing into a `vector` without making sure the index is in bounds. A security vulnerability waiting to happen.

Comment: @IInspectable -

> Indexing into a vector without making sure the index is in bounds. A security vulnerability waiting to happen.  

No, microsoft also uses it. GetKeyboardState requires an uint8 array of size 256.
All keys have values less than 256. This must be guaranteed.
Additionally, throw statements can be used with vector if desired.  
And yes, the 30 bit provides this information.

Comment: A security vulnerability is a single `SendMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, 0x100, 0)` away.

Comment: @IInspectable - God, that was something I hadn't thought of. You're right. Another program can send messages to the program via win32api. I don't know if anything other than just the system is allowed to send hardware messages.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know about C ++, but it certainly follows the same process in all languages, so you can set that pressure method to "if" and define a number that, by pressing its value, becomes one, And write. In "If" if the value of the number is equal to 1, do not do this again

In java, for example, it says:

```
int x = 0;
Button back = findViewById(R.id.button);
if(x == 0){
    back.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        //your code to do;
        x = 1;
    });
}else{}
```

that work in C++ too,

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're talking about.

Comment: are you use python or java or flutter? I can explain in these languages ​​as well

Comment: I seem to have made a typo in my answer, please read it again

Comment: Your answer doesn't need to be in any programming language, but I don't see how this works and how it relates to my question.

Comment: You want to write a button that is only for the first press return true, right? Well, the answer I gave was appropriate for this question, if I misunderstood the question, tell me

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:winapi] and [tag:c++]. An answer needs to acknowledge this. The question is also specifically about **keyboard** input. This proposed answer doesn't help with that. Since you've already earned yourself the [Peer Pressure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure?userid=18101894) badge make sure to spend some more time in the [help].